# how to sequentially append df from a dict_collection into csv or excel without overwriting the previous data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to append all the df in BDataFrame_collection to a CSV/excel file but the loop only saves the last iteration of the df. also, do you know if this program will execute without the editor? as in, will not need to be open in editor to run... thanks SOF fam....

```
import csv
import operator  
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('hey2.csv',)#file with info

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')# replacing all spaces for better op

BDataFrame_collection ={}# storage for data frames 
BList = [1,1,1,1,1,1]# size == num of work centers 

###### storing sorted df
######
BDataFrame_collection[0]= df[df.Main_work ==100]
BDataFrame_collection[1]= df[df.Main_work ==101]
BDataFrame_collection[2]= df[df.Main_work ==102]
BDataFrame_collection[3]= df[df.Main_work ==110]
BDataFrame_collection[4]= df[df.Main_work ==200]
BDataFrame_collection[5]= df[df.Main_work ==240]

###### checking for empty df
######
for i in range(0,6):# size == num of work +1 for list op
    if BDataFrame_collection[i].empty : 
        BList[i] = 0

###### Appending non-empty df
######
#for j in range(0,6):

   if BobList[j] == 1:
    BDataFrame_collection[j].to_csv('Z111_filtered.csv',index= False, 
         columns=[
        'Main_work', 'Orderup', 'Notes', 'List_help',
        'Task_elem', 'Material', 'house_Number', 'Description','Date'])
    enter code here
```

Lmk what you find, thanks

Comment: Add a `mode=’a’` to `.to_csv(...`

Comment: thanks it did work!! but it repeats the headers in rows below. how can i fix that or how can I write the file before with headers, and then append the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: ...it repeats the headers in rows below. how can i fix that

---

> **pandas 0.20.2 documentation**:
>   [**pandas.DataFrame.to_csv**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)
>
> **DataFrame.to_csv**(path_or_buf=None, sep=’, ’, na_rep=”, float_format=None, columns=None, **header=True**, index=True, index_label=None, mode=’w’, encoding=None, compression=None, quoting=None, quotechar=’”’, line_terminator=’\n’, chunksize=None, tupleize_cols=False, date_format=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal=’.’)
>
> ```
> header : boolean or list of string, default True
> ```
>
> Write out column names. If a list of string is given it is assumed to be aliases for the column names

---

> **Question**: ... but the loop only saves the last iteration of the df

Add a `mode=’a’` to `.to_csv(...`